# Send one byte of data to the hc 05 arduino bluetooth module using python on a windows 10 computer with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, arduino, bluetooth, jupyter-notebook

i have to construct car that can move based on the result the code, so  have to send byte of information by bluetooth(using the bluetooth module Hc -05) unsing python(currently using jupyter notebook, python 3). I've been trying for days with no luck.
this are code i've been using.
with the socket library

```
import socket

serverMACAddress = '00:00:00:00:00:00'
port = 4
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.connect((serverMACAddress,port))
s.send(bytes("A",'UT
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_BLUETOOTH'F-8'))
s.close()
```

And the serial and time library

```
import serial
import time


port="COM4" #This will be different for various devices,COM port.
bluetooth=serial.Serial(port, 9600)#Start communications with the bluetooth unit
bluetooth.flushInput() #This gives the bluetooth a little kick
bluetooth.write(b"A")#These need to be bytes not unicode
bluetooth.close() #Otherwise the connection will remain open until a timeout
```

this is the code for the arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial miBT(10,11);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  miBT.begin(38400);

  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  if (miBT.available()>0) {

    byte input=miBT.read();

    if(input == 'B'){          //FORWARD ---- 
        digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(5, LOW);
        digitalWrite(4, LOW);
        digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    }

    if(input == 'A'){          //BACKWARD --- 
        digitalWrite(6, LOW);
        digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    }

    if(input == 'C'){          //LEFT --- 
        digitalWrite(6, LOW);
        digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(4, LOW);
        digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    }

    if(input == 'D'){          //RIGHT --- 
        digitalWrite(5, LOW);
        digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    }

    if(input == 'E'){          //STOP --- 
        digitalWrite(6, LOW);
        digitalWrite(5, LOW);
        digitalWrite(4, LOW);
        digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

trying for days, i dont have a lot of coding skill.

for the hc05
is using the "COM4" or sending and "COM5" for recieving

```
HC-05             Arduino UNO
-----             -----------
RX       -->      Pin 11
TX       -->      Pin 10
+5v      -->      +5v
GND      -->      GND
```

Comment: *the hc05 is using the "COM4" or sending and "COM5" for recieving*, what do you mean? You only need one, why are you using two? What is COM5?

Comment: why don't you follow any of the million Arduino bluetooth tutorials on the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve by using socket and pyserial both at the same time.
As far as I know, Bluetooth sockets are not even available under Windows and by the looks of it your Python was built without Bluetooth support.

Pair your Windows 10 PC with the HC05 module. Then set an outgoing COM-Port in Windows Bluetooth settings. (Bluetooth & oterh Devices -> More Bluethooth Options).

Then use pyserial to send data.

I suggest you just follow any Arduino Bluetooth tutorial for Windows 10 step by step.